# Some help with a Linked lIst

Tags: c, linked-list

Okay I have updated my code quite a bit. I am getting a new problem, but it seems to be on a correct path. Now when I enter in the numbers it just continually spits out the first number I entered instead of moving to the next number.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <cType.h>
#include "list.h"


#define amount 3 

//Prototypes
void printList(LIST* number);

int main(){
    int i;
    int* dataPtr;
    int number;

    LIST* numberList;
    numberList = createList();

    printf("Please enter %d numbers for the linked list\n", amount);

    for(i = 0; i < amount; i++){
          printf("#%d: ", i+1);
          scanf("%d", &number);
          dataPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
          *dataPtr = number;
          addNode(numberList, dataPtr);
    }
    printList(numberList);
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}

void printList(LIST* number){
     int* dataPtr;
     while (!emptyList(number)){
           traverse(number,0, (void*)&dataPtr);
           printf("%d\n", *dataPtr);
           addNode(number, dataPtr);
     }
}
```

list.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <cType.h>

//List ADT Type Definitions
typedef struct node{
        void* dataPtr;
        struct node* link;
        } NODE;

typedef struct{
        int count;
        NODE* pos;
        NODE* head;
        NODE* rear;
        } LIST;
//Prototype Declarations
LIST* ceateList(void);

bool traverse (LIST* pList, int fromWhere, void** dataOutPtr);

int listCount (LIST* pList);
bool emptyList (LIST* pList);
bool fullList (LIST* pList);

bool addNode (LIST* pList, void* dataInPtr);
```

list.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <cType.h>

#include "list.h"

LIST* createList(void){
      LIST* list;

      list = (LIST*) malloc (sizeof(list));

      if(list){
               list->head = NULL;

               list->rear = NULL;
               list->count = 0;
      }
      return list;
}

bool addNode(LIST* pList, void* dataInPtr){
       NODE* pNew;

       if(!(pNew = (NODE*) malloc(sizeof(NODE))))
                 return false;

       pNew->dataPtr = dataInPtr;
       pNew->link =  NULL;

       if(pList->count == 0){
               pNew->link = pList->head;
               pList->head = pNew;
               if(pList->count == 0)
                 pList->rear = pNew;
       }
       else{
            pNew->link = pNew;

            if(pNew->link == NULL)
               pList->rear = pNew;
       }
       (pList->count)++;
       return true;
}


bool emptyList(LIST* pList){
     return(pList->count == 0);
}

bool fullList(LIST* pList){
     NODE* temp;

     if((temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(*(pList->head))))){
              free(temp);
              return false;
     }
     return true;
}

int listCount(LIST* pList){
    return pList->count;
}

bool traverse(LIST* pList, int fromWhere, void** dataPtrOut){
     if(pList->count == 0)
                     return false;

     if(fromWhere == 0){
                  pList->pos = pList->head;
                  *dataPtrOut = pList->pos->dataPtr;
                  return true;
     }
     else{
          if (pList->pos->link == NULL)
             return false;
          else{
               pList->pos = pList->pos->link;
               *dataPtrOut = pList->pos->dataPtr;
               return true;
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: practice question. I do not turn these in for grades

Comment: The linked list you have is somewhat confusing. You have pointers to head and rear, but the nodes only contains a forward link. Hungarian notation (p in front of variable names) and all-uppercase type names are bad style. It is old Microsoft style, but nowadays Microsoft (for .NET at least), Linus Torvalds and Bjarne Stroustrup are against it.

Comment: It is coming from a data structures and algorithms book

Comment: It seems that my traverse is screwed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `_insert()` you havn't initialized `pPre`. In C, uninitialized memory is not nessescarily `NULL`.

Also, if I were you I'd remove the `pos` pointer from the `LIST` type - using it makes your code very much not reentrant.

Comment: How would you initialize it?  
as for the pos pointer I need that for the position.

Comment: like this pPre = malloc(sizeof(NODE));?

Comment: no. Your `_insert` method expets a pointer to the location where it should insert the new data. Where do you want to insert the new data? at the beginning of the list? At the end? In the middle?

Comment: hmmm I think I will just pull that part out then. A linked list doesnt necessarily need that does it? if it does how can I fix what you said?

Answer (score 5):

```
list = (LIST*) malloc (sizeof(list));
```

You have the size of a pointer, not that of a struct.

Comment: `sizeof(list) == sizeof(LIST*) == sizeof(void*) != sizeof(LIST)`

Comment: would I just put that right after list = (LIST*) malloc (sizeof(list));?

Comment: eh, no. You would replace your line with `list = malloc(sizeof(LIST));`

Comment: still crashes after I input the amount of desired numbers. The program takes in the 5 numbers and then sits and crashes

Answer (score 0):

I think learning to use a debugger would be a good idea. It is an essential piece of any devs skill set.

If this is on a Linux system using gcc (most likely) then compile the code with -g and run it using gdb. If you need more guidance on this then says so

PS: I agree with earlier poster that you should not use all caps variable names. Traditionally all caps are for macros and constants

Comment: I am using dev C++ to compile my program. As for the way the variables are, as I said they base of this is being copied from my Data structures and algorithms book. I just happen to be changing the program that it went to originally

Comment: i dont know what 'Dev c++' is - does it have a debugger?

Comment: learning how to use it is a good investment in your time. It is always interesting and sometimes surprising to watch your code running in a debugger

Comment: I will do that. I am a little surprised I have never had a teacher make us learn it. This is my fifth programing class